# Can I make a DDS image from headerless DDS data?

Tags: windows, binary-analysis

I have some files which I've decrypted that I believe are DDS images. These files do not have a DDS header, however the data looks similar to what I've seen in other DDS images. I believe to a great extent that this data uses DXT5 texture compression. Is there any way for me make a DDS image out of these files if I dont have the file header?

Here is a link to a pastebin with the data of one of the files that I believe are headerless DDS (DXT5): https://pastebin.com/axf7ytfj

Answer (score 1):

**Can I make a DDS image from headerless DDS data?**

Yes, absolutely. The type of image (DXT5, DXT3, DXT1) can be a constant throughout the files, and the width can be inferred from the file size, model data, or some other metadata. Though, this may not be a DDS image as I am not getting a clear picture with TextureFinder

[image]